# Is lambda-calculus built over ZFC theory?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I would like to know if lambda-calculus have been built using ZFC theory ? Or if it is not, on what kind of theory lambda-calculus is based on ?

Comment: Common sense :)

Comment: Do you means that lambda calculus only lays on itself and no other theory ?

Comment: My previouis comment was just a (stupid) joke. The lambda calculus is usually considered without any foundations in mind, but it can be formalized over ZFC, or in fact many weaker systems, including Peano arithmetic.

Comment: Cool, but can you explain how ?

Comment: Lambda calculus was devised shortly after combinator theory.  They are techniques to formalize the concept of variable and function application.  ZFC came long after and has nothing to do with either of them.  Why would you presume that it has to be based on some other theory?

Comment: Because i thought that every theory should be built on axioms according to the axiomatic method. So i though that there should be an underlying theory for lambda-calculus

Comment: Being axiomatized is not the same as requiring an underlying metatheory. Lambda calculus can be axiomatized in the same way that first order logic can be, without appeal to an underlying set theory or what not.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine : first order logic does need an underlying set theory, were it only to mention "set of variables" or "set of formulas"

Comment: NO; originally, [$\lambda$ calculus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lambda-calculus/) was developed by [Alonzo Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alonzo_Church) and others explicitly as an "alternative" system with respect to set theory (based on the primitive notion of *membership*). The fundamental notion of $\lambda$-calculus is the *application* of a function to an argument; a function is a primitive notion, not defined as a set but conceived as a *rule*.

Comment: @Max, Neither of those are really essential to be able to state the lexicon or syntax of a first order language, or to conduct or recognize a proof. That it's metamathematically convenient to do so is a different matter.